# Python Tkinter delete labels before they have been added

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a simple DNS resolver application in Python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import dns.resolver
import socket
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox

# GUI
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("1200x300")
root.title("DNS RESOLVER)



# User input name server, from web address
def InputNameServer():
    NameServerEntryText = BoxTextNameServer.get()
    answers = dns.resolver.query(NameServerEntryText,'NS')
    var2 = 2
    for server in answers:
        DisplayTextNameServer = Label(root,text=server)
        DisplayTextNameServer.grid(row = var2, column = 5)
        var2 = var2 + 1
    return

BoxTextNameServer = StringVar()
InputIPAddrButton = Button(root, text = "Get the name server",command = InputNameServer)
InputIPAddrButton.grid(row = 0, column = 5)
InputIPAddrEntry = Entry(root, textvariable=BoxTextNameServer)
InputIPAddrEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 5)


root.mainloop()
```

The basic premise is that the user enters the web address in the text box, the resolver then should get the name servers via the imported DNS Resolver and should add the labels going down of the various name servers. The problem is I am unable to then delete them for when the user enters a new web address and presses the submit button. I understand the .grid_forget() and .destroy() methods but am unable to declare the label variable then delete them before the function runs and prints the labels again over the top of the previous ones. 
Apologies if I have over complicated things, in short enter address, press submit, print labels, enter new address, press submit, delete previous labels, print new labels.

Comment: Can we get a working MWE? Or just descriptions? From what I see you create new Labels with text "THS" then immediately destroy those (which should remove them from the frame, are we in a Frame?) and then add a new label under and next to them with new text that never gets destroyed? Why the empty return? My advice is to have a dedicated Frame to hold this, have it as an inherited Frame object i.e. DNSNameFrame and have it have a destroy method with `for widget in frame.winfo_children():   widget.destroy()` in it. Call that method before you print new labels.

Comment: I'll edit the code accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Still hard to have a Minimal *Working* Example when I'm missing personal dns resolver modules. Next time just put in a substitute function that returns something if it's mainly unrelated to the question you're asking.

Anyhow this is what I was talking about:

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
import tkMessageBox

def dummy_DNS_Resolver():
    return "IT'S HARD TO HELP PEOPLE WHEN THEY GIVE "+\
            "MWE'S THAT NEED THEIR SPECIAL MODULES"

class DNSNameFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, relief=RAISED, borderwidth=1)
        self.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.parent = parent

    def update(self):
        self.clearTable()

        servername = self.parent.ServerInputFrame.getServerName()
        for i in range(0, 10):
            Label(self, text=servername, relief=RIDGE).grid(row=i, column=0)
            Label(self, text=dummy_DNS_Resolver()).grid(row=i,column=1)

    def clearTable(self):
        for widget in self.winfo_children(): 
            widget.destroy()

class ServerInputFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, relief=RAISED, borderwidth=1)
        self.pack(side=TOP, fill=Y, expand=1)

        Label(self, text="Enter Server:").pack(side=TOP)

        self.serverName = StringVar()
        self.entry = Entry(self, width=70, textvariable=self.serverName)
        self.entry.pack(side=TOP)

        Button(self, text="Run", width=30, command=parent.update).pack(side=BOTTOM)

    def getServerName(self):
        return self.serverName.get()


class MainWindow(Tk):
    def __init__(self, geom="1200x300", title="DNS RESOLVER"):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title(title)
        self.geometry(geom)
        self.initGui()

    def initGui(self):
        self.DNSNameFrame = DNSNameFrame(self)
        self.ServerInputFrame = ServerInputFrame(self)

    def update(self):
        self.DNSNameFrame.update()

app = MainWindow()
app.mainloop()
```

It's a bit more lengthy than the average monolithic way people use to do Tkinter in but I find it way easier and all only for a cost of 1 additional `__init__` function. Additionally each of the Frame child classes can be placed in different files and then imported into the MainWindow which reduces the usual clutter when dealing with Tk.

Separating your logical working units of your GUI helps you deal with each of it individually which is easier.

The part you're most interested in should be the DNSNameFrame. Before every table update you clear the table. You populate your table by grabbing the `servername` from your ServerInputFrame over the `self.parent` which is MainFrame. You send that to your dns module and retrieve some result. You loop through that result and paste the appropriate servernames. When I did it I made it a table, but now I saw that you just have a list, it should still be easy enough to modify the code for your needs.

Works in Ipython 2.7 Notebook, win7 x64.

Comment: I don't know what else to add, the code I have above when copied into a .py file works perfectly and so is by my definition and minimal working example. Thanks anyway though

Comment: I'm not trying to pick a fight here or something so don't take it much to hearth. But I am saying that [MWE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should be as short as it can be (true) but provide all parts needed for it to work (false) and be verifiable (false). In any case just by using the code I gave you by altering the `for` loop range and substituting the function call for your module function call you should get it to work just as you need it to.